# jQueryUI Tabs with POST data ERROR 405

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, http-status-code-405

Versions: jQuery 1.11, jQueryUI 1.11

Trying to convert pre jQuery 1.9 tabs to support jQuery 1.11, which use a POST to send data to the other tabs. What was so easy with ajaxOptions is now quite hard.

jQuery Code:

```
        $("#dtabs").tabs({
            beforeLoad: function(event, ui) {       
            ui.ajaxSettings.type="POST";
            ui.ajaxSettings.hasContent = true;
            ui.jqXHR.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", ui.ajaxSettings.contentType);
            ui.ajaxSettings.data=jQuery.param({testoption: 'Hello'}, ui.ajaxSettings.traditional);  
            ui.jqXHR.fail(function() {
              ui.panel.html("Oops.");
            });
          }
        });
```

HTML:

```
<div id="dtabs"><ul>
<li><a href="a.php">test1</a></li>
<li><a href="b.php">test2</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

When testing them I get "405 Method Not Allowed". All advice I've found is regarding cross-domain, but this isn't cross-domain. This is running locally (127.0.0.1).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: the issue is `post` request is send to `get` handler at server.

Comment: What server side language are you using?

Comment: This means "method not allowed". e.g  if you try to POST to a URL that doesn't allow POST, then the server will return a status 405.

Comment: It's using PHP. To be clear, the only thing that's changed is jQuery and jQueryUI version. It POSTed fine before, same URL, same browser, same server, etc